# Sentence Parsing

Tags: parsing

> なにせ〈レギオン〉に匹敵する機動性だけを主眼に開発して、安全性への考慮が全く欠けた代物だ。結果、テスト段階でオペレーターは片端から体を痛めて脱落。実戦配備後の正規プロセッサーも、何人かは〈レギンレイヴ〉に喰い殺されたようなものだ。
>
> シンやライデン達は運用に耐えられているが、それは彼らがエイティシックスだからだ。成長期にさしかかる十代初めから、**こちらも**搭乗者への配慮がまるでなかった共和国の〈ジャガーノート〉を駆り続け、その負荷に適応する形で体が成長した、**その結果**。

86─エイティシックス─Ep.2 ─ラン・スルー・ザ・バトルフロント─〈上〉
安里アサト

What does the bold こちらも refer to? Is こちらもその結果。the main clause of the last sentence? If not, what role does こちらも play in that sentence? How should I parse the last sentence?

Answer (score 1):

This is partly a guess, but こちらも refers to ジャガーノート, and as for その結果, その refers to the preceding "成長期に....成長した". The implicit subject of the last sentence is "シンやライデンたちは運用に耐えられている理由は". So it seems to be elaborating on "彼らがエイティシックスである".

(Please correct as per the context). So the last paragraph roughly says,

> Shin and Ryden do tolerate レギンレイヴ, but it is because they are 86. That is, they were on ジャガーノート since early teens, **which was also** designed driver-unfriendlily , and grew up adapting to the stress, **the result of which** (is that Shin and Ryden manage レギンレイヴ).

---

So the particular こちらも is like an adverb meaning "also". An example:

- ポーランド語はこちらも初心者に厳しい言語だ (talking about, say, Russian previously) Polish is also a language difficult for beginners.

In relative clause:

- こちらも初心者に厳しい言語であるポーランド語を勉強し始めた.